# setup coredata, before appdelegate loads my mainWindow.xib

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data, xib, mainwindow

I have setup coredata in my appDelegate, but it first loads the mainWindow.xib and the corresponding controllers+views in that xib file. Those controllers need to have a managedObjectContext to load properly. And after the xib is unarchived it runs the code in my appDelegate.

How can i setup my coredata and then load the mainWIndow.xib? Or just make sure coredata is initialized properly before unarchiving my mainWindows.xib?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could override `awakeFromNib` on your `UIApplicationDelegate` subclass, and setup Core Data there. This method will be called once all objects has been unarchived from your nib file, but before their instances begin to do their work. See `awakeFromNib` as your last chance to tweak any behavior before the instances start running.

Observe:

- When overriding `awakeFromNib` you must call `[super awakeFromNib]`, or else your superclass might not initialize properly.
- The order of the calls to `awakeFromNib` is undefined, so you may never send messages to any other objects from the same Nib from within `awakeFromNib`. As a bonus this also means that `awakeFromNib` is guaranteed to run **before** any other object in the same Nib needs your services and sends any messages to you.

Comment: It seems that, using awakeFromNib in my AppDelegate is sufficient enough.